# what should breakpoint list be in detrending EEG signal

Tags: signal-processing

I am working on Decoding English alphabets letter using EEG signal information. I wanted to remove the baseline drift from EEG signal and now I am not sure about what my breakpoints-input should be. 
I am using `scipy.signal.detrend()`
This is the part where I am having a problem with. `DetrendData = detrend(rawData,axis=1,type="linear",bp=[i for i in range(0,250,4)])`

which `rawData.shape = (8,250)`

Comment: There is no generic answer for this question.  The answer entirely depends on your data and what you want to get out of it.  My suspicions is, if you're putting in hundreds of breakpoints at places that aren't correlated with any feature of the data or it's collection, `scipy.signal.detrend` is probably not the tool you want to use. For example, have you considered using a high pass filter?